# Return zipped json string

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, zip

I have a very large json string and I want to send that user using web api. I can do this by write json file to hard disk and zip it. Is there are any other way to do it without write to hard disk.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("catalog")]
    public HttpResponseMessage ReturnCatalog(string password)
    {
        var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        jsonSerialiser.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
        var json = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(items);

        File.WriteAllText(@"e:\data.json", json);

        using (ZipArchive zip = ZipFile.Open(@"e:\data.zip", ZipArchiveMode.Create))
        {
            zip.CreateEntryFromFile(@"e:\data.json", "data.json");
        }

        var path = @"e:\data.zip";

        var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);

        HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/zip");
        return result;
    }
```

This seems a very bad method(with multiple users). Can anyone suggest me an alternative way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to zip a single JSON? I'm not sure you'll get the expected compression you're expecting. Why not return a `DeflateStream`?

Comment: The hard drive is buffered by both the operating system and the hardware.  If the file doesn't exist long, it may never actually be written to the disk.  You might be solving a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: @Steve You wouldn't want to relay on an implementation detail in the OS to do work. He should be doing this in memory.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov  I _didn't_ say he should rely on an implementation detail of the OS.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov yes 6.43mb json goes to 867kb zip. can you suggest me a method do this without writing hard drive.

Comment: I know this is late, but you might wanna use MemoryStream